# How can I count runs in a sequence of increasing and decreasing numbers?

Tags: r, count, sequence

In R, if I have a sequence defined as the vector

```
u <- c(0.86,0.11,0.23,0.03,0.13,0.06,0.55,0.64,0.87,0.1)
```

I would like the unbroken subsequences (run up) of maximal length within which the ui's increase monotonically, that is, the sequence starts with a rup up of length 1 (0.86), followed by a run up pf length 2 (0.11,0.23), then another run up of length 2 (0.03,0.13), the a run up of length 4 (0.06,0.55,0.64,0.87) and finally a run up of length 1 (0.10).
I would like to have those numbers (1,2,2,4,1) in a vector, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Loop through the vector and keep track of the streak.

```
u <- c(0.86,0.11,0.23,0.03,0.13,0.06,0.55,0.64,0.87,0.1) 
num=numeric()
count=1
for (i in 2:length(u)) {
  if (u[i]>u[i-1]) {
    count=count+1
  } else {
    num=c(num, count)
    count=1
  }
  if (i==length(u)) {
    num=c(num, count)
  }
}
num

[1] 1 2 2 4 1
```

Comment: Thanks! The way you did it was the way I was doing it but I was missing some details.

Comment: @CarlosV.Ramírez Glad it helped. Appreciate if you could accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Base R option using `tapply` :

```
u <- c(0.86,0.11,0.23,0.03,0.13,0.06,0.55,0.64,0.87,0.1) 
unname(tapply(u, cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(u) < 0)), length))
#[1] 1 2 2 4 1
```

Using `diff` we calculate difference between every consecutive value and create a new group when the difference goes below 0. Using `tapply` we calculate `length` of each group.